# unable to launch custom brackets.exe

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

I have created a desktop app using brackets-shell version sprint-38. I have done the following changes.

1. config.h -changed APP_NAME from 'Brackets' to 'MyBrackets'.
2. appshell_config.gypi - changed appname from 'Brackets' to 'MyBrackets'.
3. Gruntfile - changed build.name from 'Brackets' to 'MyBrackets'.

After building brackets-shell with these changes i used to get 'MyBrackets.exe'  
inside brackets-shell/release folder.  
while executing the exe one file chooser popup comes, and node & MyBrackets.exe processes will start in the background.  
his works fine with Sprint38,But after migrating to brackets-shell tag version release-1.3 or master, this dose not work. The file chooser is not coming as well as no node process starts.  
Is any thing i am missing with the latest release ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo!!!
I got the problem. actually xcopy command is not generating properly in MyBrackets.vscsproj file.  and this is well know problem i think so. To fix this problem one fix-msvc.sh file has written.

Since brackets.vscsproj name is hardcoded here so changes is not reflecting in my MyBrackets.vscsproj